# Что быстрее sql или файл?

Tags: кэширование, файлы, php, sql

Вот у меня вопрос. Написал движок, теперь я его пытаюсь оптимизировать. И хотел спросить, что быстрее работает скул запрос или запрос в php через include.

1. Есть смысл урезать запросы?
2. Или на скорость не повлияет?
3. Если разницы нет, то что дает больше нагрузку на сервер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обработка файлов происходит быстрее чем выполнение запросов в БД. Для небольшого объема данных файл - лучше. Но если объемы большие, то выбирать уже не приходится, БД - однозначно!
Работа над оптимизацией SQL-запросов, очень важный процесс в реализации задания, т.к. хороший запрос может снизить нагрузку на сервер в несколько раз.

А вот сравнение sql запроса с функцией include мне что-то непонятно...

Comment: я имел введу в том что у меня  примеру будет кэшироватся sql запрос в файле к примеру cache/4ety484t84.php
и мне чтобы открыть данные надо пользоваться функцией include(). Но для использование этой функции тоже надо ресурсы, так само как sql запрос. Хотел спросит что больше ресурсов будет требовать функция include() или запрос sql.

Comment: А, ну в вашем случае - кеширование это лучший вариант, нежели каждый раз выполнять sql-запрос

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите кэшировать запросы к БД, то почему бы не воспользоваться стандартными средствами [mySQL](http://fastsql.ru/2011/01/03/optimiziruem-mysql-query-cache/)? Если вы используете БД или планируете работать с большим объемом данных, то это - ваш вариант. В противном случае можете пользоваться файлами, почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разграничим задачи:

1. Выбрать запись из списка с фильтрами (10 позиций, начиная с 20 в категории товары, в цене от 100 до 1000) - это запрос к БД, так как организация этого на файлах будет сложнореализуемой либо медленной.
2. Вам нужно закшировать результат работы (генерация меню, страница) - это обычно на основе выборки из БД и обработки пишется в файл.
3. Вым нужно вывести одну запись из 1000000. Либо БД, но её размер будет внушающим уважение, и вряд ли это будет слишком быстро. Либо файл с жесткой структурой (например двоичный).

То есть ответ на ваш вопрос во многом зависит от задачи.

Оптиально для оптимизации и простоты есть генерация+кеширование.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так все усложнять? Просто-напросто делаете нужный запрос и все, зачем подключать что-либо для того, что бы выполнить тот же запрос, но из другого файла?

Comment: Подключается результат выполнения запроса, а не сам запрос. Потому если запрос выполняется десятки-тысячи раз, то имеет смысл записать его результат в кэш и не мучить сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что оптимально в этом варианте лучше использовать урезанную версию MySQL Lite, если, конечно, есть возможность настройки сервера под себя. Я лично использую XML файлы, с них легко при помощи SimpleXML можно все вытаскивать - скорость выборки невероятно высока.